# Xamarin Android dialog.PositiveButtonClicked not working

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-asynctask, dialog, task

I would like to have some code run (use Intent to go to new Activity) when the user clicks the Ok button in a dialog (DialogFragment)

I see in the debugger it hits the line of code for .Show.
But it seems to skip past the PositiveButtonClicked and just go to the lines of code after that.

Why is PositiveButtonClicked not working?

I've tried adding extra lines before and after, as well as inside. Ive double checked that the dialog has a positivebutton set to "Ok".I also have other dialogs with PositiveButtonClicked that work on this Activity, so im not sure why this one doesnt work

**C#:**

```
private async Task ProcessExistingFamilyMembers(AccountAddFamilyMemberState state)
{
    
    cafdialog.Show(this.FragmentManager, "cafdialog");
    cafdialog.PositiveButtonClicked += (args1) =>
    { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(OrderSummaryActivity));
        intent.PutExtra<AccountSubscriptionInfo>("account_subscription_info", info);
        SubscriptionChangeInfo changeInfo = new SubscriptionChangeInfo() { Last4ofCC = aafmi.Last4ofCC, NextBillingDate = aafmi.NextBillingDate };
        intent.PutExtra<SubscriptionChangeInfo>("subscription_change_info", changeInfo);
        StartActivity(intent);
        Finish();
    };
}
```

Comment: You can try my solution in my answer. For more information, you can refer to [DialogFragment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/specialized-fragment-classes#alert-dialog) by official.

Answer (score 1):

You can create AlertDialogFragment class that inherits `DialogFragment`:

```
[Obsolete]
    public class AlertDialogFragment : DialogFragment
    {
        [Obsolete]
        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity)
                .SetMessage("This is my dialog.")
                .SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sender, args) =>
                {
                    //use Intent to go to new Activity
                    var intent = new Intent(Context, typeof(Activity1));
                    StartActivity(intent);
                })
                .SetTitle("Custom Dialog");
            return builder.Create();
        }
    }
```

In MainActivity.cs, call ShowDialog() in OnCreate() :

```
...
[System.Obsolete]
#pragma warning disable CS0809 // Obsolete member overrides non-obsolete member
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
#pragma warning restore CS0809 // Obsolete member overrides non-obsolete member
        {
            ...
            ShowDialog();
        }

       [System.Obsolete]
        public void ShowDialog()
        {
            var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            var dialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
            dialogFragment.Show(transaction, "dialog_fragment");
        }
```